# Uneven split of amperage from battery

Tags: electrical-engineering, battery

I'm currently trying to replace a broken battery for an electric moped, but the old one had two power ports,  one for the engine and one for the lights/horn.  I haven't been able to find anything that seems suited for splitting a 48volt 30amp connection into one 25 amp and one 5 amp. 
If anyone could share a blueprint and a quick explanation it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you please share make and model of the electric mope?

Comment: a part number for the correct battery may help

Comment: It's not the power:  it's the output voltage.  If they're the same voltage (highly unlikely) the most you'd need is an external fuse.

Answer (score 1):

The two different circuits in parallel will draw current from the battery depending on their relative resistances you don't need to 'supply' a specific current to specific circuits.

Having said that :

- the components in each circuit need to be rated for the maximum  current which that circuit will draw.
- Each outlet should be protected by a fuse or circuit breaker of an appropriate rating, ideally as close to the battery as possible.
- It is entirely likely that some ancillaries work off a lower voltage than the motor (probably 12v) in this case you will need a transformer or voltage converter to provide the appropriate voltage.

Comment: indeed seperate voltages is probably why the batt had seperate ports to begin with.